# Whiptail: How can I handle an error when a gauge is running?

Tags: bash, whiptail

Here is a for loop, which is running a regular Whiptail gauge. I this loop, a command might throw an error and I would like to display a message box `--msgbox` displaying the error. After that, I could like the script to continue it's way like the error never happened.

Here is an oversimplified code as an example. Here is it's behavior and the code:

- A for list is iterating on an array with 3 numbers and 1 letter.
- For the 2 first numbers, a command using them is executed and a gauge is increasing by 25%.
- For the letter, the command will fail, and I would like to display a `--msgbox` with the error waiting me to press enter
- For the last number, the same behavior than for the 2 others.

```
#!/bin/bash

array=("1" "2" "A" "3")

i=0
for element in "${array[@]}"; do
        command $element #This command will fail with any non int value.
        echo "XXX"
        echo $(expr 100 / 4 \* $i)
        echo ${array[$i]}
        echo "XXX"
        i=$((i+1))
        sleep 1
done | whiptail --title "Gauge" --gauge "Wait" 10 80 0
```

I have already tried few things like `command $element || whiptail --title "Exception" --msgbox "Error!" 10 80`. However, as the whiptail for the message box is in the loop for the gauge, the output is broken.

The problem is maybe coming from my design?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's been a while that this has been asked, you can output to a different output descriptor. In my case, I output to a separate log file like so:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

array=("1" "2" "A" "3")

i=0
for element in "${array[@]}"; do
        command $element #This command will fail with any non int value.
        echo "XXX" >> logs.log
        echo $(expr 100 / 4 \* $i)
        echo ${array[$i]} >> logs.log
        echo "XXX" >> logs.log
        i=$((i+1))
        sleep 1
done | whiptail --title "Gauge" --gauge "Wait" 10 80 0
```